# ASP.NET Webforms Checkbox event sending argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I basically have a lot of checkboxs calling the same function. To identify the action that it each one is suppose to trigger, I was thinking on passing an argument for the function that is going to be triggered.

My checkbox is as this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkBoxRegul" runat="server" CssClass="" Visible="false" OnCheckedChanged='checkBoxRegularizarChangedEvent' AutoPostBack="True" />
```

My function is as this:

```
protected void checkBoxRegularizarChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
}
```

How can I send and receive information via EventArgs?

Thanks!

Comment: One way to do this is to check the ID of the `sender`, which you could do once you cast it to the proper type.  Based on the ID you could then determine what to do.  I don't think you can directly put custom information in the `EventArgs` argument though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing here, but from what I gather you should be looking into a javascript solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's not simple but it is doable. EventArgs (e) can not store additional info directly, but you can create a custom control with a custom event that can contain additional info.

Step 1: Create a `CheckBoxEventArgs` class that inherits from `EventArgs`(`CheckBoxEventArgs.cs`). Add public properties to hold the information that you need.

```
public class CheckBoxEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public string ValueOne { get; set; }
    public string ValueTwo { get; set; }
     
}
```

Step 2: Add a custom .ascx control to your project (`CustomCheckBox.ascx`). Add a checkbox to the HTML.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CustomCheckBox.ascx.cs" Inherits="CustomControls.CustomCheckBox" %>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkCheckBox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkCheckBox_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
```

Customize the codebehind as follows:

- Define the CheckChanged event with a custom EventHandler
- Add properties to store the custom checkbox values
- Add a text property and pass the value through to the checkbox text
- Respond the the CheckChanged event and raise your custom event

```
//CustomCheckBox.cs

public partial class CustomCheckBox : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    public event EventHandler<CheckBoxEventArgs> CheckChanged;
    
    public string ValueOne { get; set; }
    public string ValueTwo { get; set; }
    
    public string Text
    {
        get { return chkCheckBox.Text; }
        set { chkCheckBox.Text = value; }
    }
    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void chkCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
        if (CheckChanged != null)
        {
             var args = new CheckBoxEventArgs()
             {
                 ValueOne = this.ValueOne,
                 ValueTwo = this.ValueTwo
             };
            CheckChanged(this, args);
        }
    
    }

}
```

Step 3: Add the CustomCheckBox.ascx to your page and register the OnCheckChanged event.

```
<%@ Register src="CustomCheckBox.ascx" tagname="CustomCheckBox" tagprefix="uc1" %>
...
<uc1:CustomCheckBox ID="CustomCheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckChanged="CustomCheckBox1_OnCheckChanged" ValueOne="one" ValueTwo="two"/>
```

Add code to the codebehind page to respond to your custom checkchanged event, and use the custom values (they are available directly from the customEventArgs that you created (e) )

```
public partial class PageOne : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void CustomCheckBox1_OnCheckChanged(object sender, CheckBoxEventArgs e)
    {
        var val1 = e.ValueOne;
        var val2 = e.ValueTwo;

        //use custom values
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, You cannot, [EventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) does not have any property to hold what you want.

You will need to either map each checkbox to different event handlers or check the value of your checkboxes in checkBoxRegularizarChangedEvent.

Or... like Tim said, you could check the sender class.

There is no "right" answer, it depends on your needs.

Hope it helps.